# Unable to send the data to Openbravo ERP through HTTP POST

Tags: java, web-services

In HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost(url);
what should be the url in case if I'm trying to access a module in Openbravo-erp which is in localhost:8080.

Answer (score 0):

HttpPost class has three constructors

```
HttpPost() 
HttpPost(String uri) 
HttpPost(URI uri)
```

for the second constructors you can pass like below.

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/openbravo/ws/dal/Product");
```

Hope this helps !.

Comment: I tried it but it throws an error at the post.execute(request);

Comment: What would be the code under doPost(String path, HttpServletRequest request HttpServletResponse response), which is declared in the openbravo module.

Comment: can you tell me the error that you get ,when execute the code ? if possible , please post the code here .

Comment: HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(getUrl()+"/ws/com.sahaj.webservices.salesrequest/");
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("quantity", product));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("commpharmacist", name));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

Comment: the error or exception that you get , when you execute httpclient.execute(httppost); Are you getting malframedexception or any different exception ?